# how to view or decode a .kotlin_module

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, apk

We have been given an apk to add some functionality to. in the files we have *.kotlin_modules

In intellij / bytecode viewer / etc is there a way to view or de-compile these files to expand functionality in them?

in bytecode viewer the files preview content as `? ? ? ?`

in intellij idea ultimate the `kotlin -> show kotlin byte code` is greyed out

Answer (score 1):

You can use **kotlinx-metadata-jvm** library to read and modify these files: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/kotlinx-metadata/jvm/ReadMe.md

As for IDEA support: I created a feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38112, you can watch it for updates.